# How to call a bash script that has getopts with curl command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, getopts

I have a script that contains a simple "getopts".

I found out that only calling it like this works:

```
bash <(http://domain.com/myscript.sh) -a
```

Why calling it like this does not work?

```
curl –L http://domain.com/myscript.sh | bash -s -a
```

Is there any different way to call it with curl? ( other than what I supplied )

I do not want to download it but only use curl in order to execute it.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that arguments after `-s` starting with `-` are still subject to being parsed as an option to bash (see `help set`):

```
printf "arguments: %s\n" "$*"
shopt -o | grep noglob
```

Tests:

```
$ bash -s -f < script.sh
arguments: 
noglob          on
$ bash -s -a < script.sh
arguments: 
noglob          off
$ bash -s -z < script.sh
bash: -z: invalid option
$ bash -s x < script.sh
arguments: x
noglob          off
```

To prevent it, simply use `--`:

```
curl –L http://domain.com/myscript.sh | bash -s -- -a
```

From bash's manual:

> A -- signals the end of options and disables further option
>   processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and
>   arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts ":a" opt; do
  case $opt in
    a)
      echo "-a was triggered!" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Test:

```
$ bash script.sh -s -- -a < script.sh
-a was triggered!
```

Comment: @AsafMagen I hope you accept the answer if it's enough :)

Comment: i do. do i need to do something?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
curl -L http://domain.com/myscript.sh | bash /dev/stdin -a
```